# virtual machine and client OS

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I just adjusted my client OS to scale its display to fit the host Windows virtual box and things began to look warped. I want to undo this new setting and re-employ its display to be back to the normal state in which all currently stretched text and images look are no longer stretched. I do not know how that can be done.

I tried to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> but it displayed a message box asking me the location I want to open.

Comment: Yes, I am using VBox

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific??

Comment: I want the client OS to fit its size into the host container whenever I resize the container, I chouse view->scale to windows(?) then the client OS is STRETCHED when I resize the container.

Comment: Are you talking about the resolution?

Comment: Can you please be way more specific? Which operating system is the host? Which one the guest? Do you have any VirtualBox guest additions installed? Can you take a screenshot to show us what you mean? Why do you think pressing `Ctrl-L` would work? Where did you find that command? Please [edit] your post, and try a more structural approach. What do you want to achieve? How does it currently look like?

Answer (score 0):

The client image is initiated by the client's video display based on what the host system is telling is available for a graphics display (The stretching and scaling you are trying). Some OS's will automatically detect hardware changes and adjust dynamically. Apparently the unspecified systems that you are using don't handle this dynamically. So instead, you need to manually readjust the client's video display to some standard size, and also set the host to display it without scaling etc.

Answer (score 0):

To disable **Scale Mode**, press <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. By default, the **Host** key is mapped to the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

[image: screen shot]